# want to access connection object in another class

Tags: java

Here, i had return connection in one class and trying to access the connection object in another class where i am writing my prepared statement to execute an query and update the table.Please suggest whether it is correct way, if not post your advice.
Thanks In Advance

## Connection Class

```
public class dbConnection {

    public Connection dbconnect()
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String db = "gup";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";
        try{
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
            if(conn == null){
                System.out.println("Connection is not established");
            }
            return conn ;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null ;
    }
    
}
```

## Prepared Statement Class to Insert data

```
public class InsertingData {
    
   
    public void insertfile(String fpath,String fname,String fext)
    {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        // Connection conn = null ;
        dbConnection dbcon = new dbConnection();
        pstmt = (PreparedStatement) dbcon.dbconnect();
        //Create the statement object
        String sql = "insert into FileDetails (folder_path,file_name,file_extension)" + "values (?,?,?)";
        try
        {
        
        //ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, fpath);
        pstmt.setString(2, fname);
        pstmt.setString(3, fext);
        pstmt.executeQuery(sql);
        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            System.out.println(se);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Error message? Stack Trace?  `pstmt = (PreparedStatement) dbcon.dbconnect();` won't work because you can't cast the `Connection` returned by `dbconnect()` to a `PreparedStatement`.  You get a `PreparedStatement` from the connection object with `prepareStatement()`, not by casting it.

Comment: The error is com.mysql.jdbc.Connection cannot be cast to java.sql.PreparedStatement.
Okay,then how to use connection object in these class.

Comment: By reading the javadoc of Connection to discover what methods you can call and what they do. Jim Garrison aready told you about connection.prepareStatement(). Read the javadoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to cast the Connection to a PreparedStatement, use the Connection to get a prepared statement. Replace

```
pstmt = (PreparedStatement) dbcon.dbconnect();
String sql = "insert into FileDetails (folder_path,file_name,file_extension)" + "values (?,?,?)";
....
pstmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

with

```
Connection conn = dbcon.dbconnect();
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into FileDetails (folder_path,file_name,file_extension)" + "values (?,?,?)");
....
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

see also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html